# Symfony2 console must be selected mac

Tags: php, symfony, netbeans

I am running symfony2 project on netbeans at mac, and I am getting this error when I try to open one new symfony2 project.[image: error message shows at symfony2]

In the background if you look it says I am already using composer version ...

[image: no composer found at netbeans]
And at netbeans also I cannot find the composer.
i have also install composer globally like ...

```
$ curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
$ sudo mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
```

Anyone has any idea what am I doing wrong or how I can fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Well i had the same trouble few weeks ago.

You have to dl a symfony.zip and then in netbeans go into

Tools > Options > PHP > Frameworks and Tools > symfony2

And then enter the path to your .zip archive

Hope this may help.

I dont have my MAC with me right now. I could check tonight if still needed.

Comment: i have already done that, but that did not help, thanks anyway